# Emacs+geben: Open local files when debugging instead of remote ones

Tags: php, debugging, emacs, xdebug, geben

### Prerequisites

- Web server with PHP and xdebug. htdocs directory shared via NFS.
- Developer machine running emacs with geben. Files edited via NFS mount of server htdocs directory.

### The problem

When debugging PHP web applications with emacs and [geben](http://code.google.com/p/geben-on-emacs/), the web app's files that are opened are not the local files but "dummy" files that represent the file contents on the server.

The main problem I have with that is that I can't directly edit the files because I'd change them on the server, which causes several things:

- changing a temporary file causes emacs to ask me for ssh login credentials
- changing a temporary file, emacs wants to reload the original open files because they changed
- jump marks are not available on the temporary files

Ideally, a mapping of remote paths to local paths would need to be setup, but I think that's currently not possible with geben.
Are there solutions to this problem?

Comment: I know this question is old, but I'm struggling with this right now. Any update would be nice.

Comment: I've not found a solution.

Comment: can't find a way of doing that. I have Apache running inside a docker container, so Geben sees it as another host, but in fact it's a local directory mounted. Best way so far is to install an ssh server inside docker container and configure ssh keys to avoid login credentials.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what OS you are using, but you may have more success using [sshfs](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html), as it seems that that is what you are using to connect to the remote server.

Try setting up your ssh with a private key. That way you will not get asked for the password so much.

Comment: ssh has absolutely nothing do do in here. I explicitely said that I use NFS, and apart from that geben opens a dummy file regardless of the underlying filesystem type.

Comment: Interesting. Why this then: "changing a temporary file causes emacs to ask me for ssh login credentials"?

Comment: because emacs/geben knows that it's a remote server and assumes that you can ssh into the server to modify the file. This is the behavior I don't want - I want the remote-to-local mapping.